# optimal chain for resolve in ivy

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, ivy, archiva

I have some project's that integrates ivy, i publish my artifact in two possible repositories, local, that respond to a folder, and beta, that respond to a server where archiva is installed and where i share my jars with my colleague.
Now the problem: i need to find a way to build a resolution chains that do this things:

1. search between the various repository the latest.integration.
2. retrieve that jar.
3. if that jar is already in my cache do not have to download it.
4. if the artifact in the cache has the same version of the artifact in one of the repository take the latest in chronology's order.

now i have try everything that's the setting

**Ivy setting**

```
<chain name="resolvechain">
    <ibiblio name="b1" root="archivaURLforbeta" m2compatible="true" checkmodified="true" latest="latest-time"/>
    <filesystem name="b2" checkmodified="true" >
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern}" />
    </filesystem>
    <ibiblio name="b3" root="archivaURLforrelease" m2compatible="true" latest="latest-time"/>
    <ibiblio name="b4" m2compatible="true"/>
</chain>
```

that's the target of resolve in the **Build.xml** file:

```
<ivy:settings file="${archiva.set}" />
<ivy:resolve refresh="true" resolveMode="dynamic" changing="true"/>
<ivy:retrieve sync="true" overwritemode="newer" pattern="./lib/[artifact]-[type]-[revision](.[ext])" />
```

and that's an example on how the dependency are written in **ivy.xml** file

```
<dependency org="organization" name="module-name" rev="latest.integration"  transitive="false" conf="default" />
```

the questions are two:
First of all is there any error according to my needs?
Second, what i'm trying to do, is possible?

i asked these two questions because it seems to me that setting checkmodified true and changing true let my application skip entirely my cache, and my projects continuing to download the artifacts every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution searching between different questions here in stackoverflow and in some issues solution in the ivy comunity with my colleagues.
The FileSystem need **it's own latest-time strategy**, every resolve take note of their own modules last date revision.
Here the mod in the code:

```
<filesystem name="b2" checkmodified="true" latest="latest-time">
    <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern}" />
</filesystem>
```